# Diff on a row in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, diff

I am wondering if there is an easy way to compare a couple of rows of MySQL data.

In particular, what i have is a table containing a list of setting values for each user.

A user can modify these settings in a gui in no problem.

Now, what i am trying to do is : whenever a user saves new data, i want to find the diff between the old data and the to-be-saved data to find out which columns where changed and later save to a log...

The way i am doing this right now is reading the row corresponding to the user before saving and comparing it, variable by variable to find the changed data but i find it slow and i am wondering if there is a smarter way to do this, perhaps inside a mysql query (maybe using a temporary table?) or by using some php mysql function i don't know about...

I hope you have some ideas for me.

(I checked this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218499/mysql-diff-tool , but that turns out to be a lot different than what i am looking for)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If all you want to do is log changes, consider using [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/triggers.html). Then you don't have to worry about manually checking whenever rows are updated.

Comment: @MichaelMior just realized i skipped your comment :( thanks for that, its very helpful too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with the `array_diff_assoc()` function in PHP.

Here we have two rows of data in php arrays.

```
$newValues = array_diff_assoc($afterRow, $beforeRow);
```

It will return an array where any column values have changed or been added.

**Edit**

To do this in MySQL, you'd need them in name value pairs, something like this:

```
Prefs
----------------------------------------------
UserID   TransactionID   Name       Value
----------------------------------------------
1        1               Font       Sans Serif
1        1               Color      Red
1        1               Height     100
1        1               Width      400

1        2               Font       Verdana
1        2               Color      Red
1        2               Height     100
1        2               Indent     50
```

TransactionID 1 is the old row and Transaction ID 2 is the new row:

```
SELECT * FROM Prefs new
  LEFT JOIN Prefs old
  ON new.Name = old.Name
    AND new.Value = old.Value
  WHERE UserID = 1
    AND new.TransactionID = 2
    AND old.TransactionID = 1
    AND (old.Name IS NULL OR old.Value IS NULL)
```

If my logic is right, should yield:

```
----------------------------------------------
UserID   TransactionID   Name       Value
----------------------------------------------
1        2               Font       Verdana
1        2               Indent     50
```

Comment: +0 I deleted my answer which contained a very similar solution. It only accounts for new _elements_. It doesn't account for _changed values_.

Comment: @mmmshuddup, if you're saying that the above solution doesn't account for changed values, then I say that my eyes deceive me. Try it and let me know.

Comment: mmm no.. I swear when I wrote that comment, the content of your answer was different! lol. I will re-read it and tell you what I get. For the interim time, I retract my previous comment. :)

Comment: sorry for the delay, but YES ! that is what i am looking for, i don't have both rows in php since old settings are in mysql and new ones are in php, but i can make some quick changes and i am good to go :) thanks !

Comment: I've opened a similar question but I need to compare the text: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56583317/creating-a-diff-patch-function-in-mysql-for-varchar-fields . Do you have any suggestion?