# Creating a Diff Patch function in MySQL (for varchar fields)

Tags: mysql, diff

I would like to obtain a MySQL **function** which calculates the **[difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff)** between the 2 varchar fields in a **[diff patch format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff)**. Any developer which have familiarity with SVN or Git knows how a "**patch**" file is calculated through a **diff** tool, I would like to create this procedure in MySQL.

Let's take two very long string from a varchar field in MySQL. The two long text which are the 1st and 2nd version of the same article / piece of code. They are about 1000 words long and differ just for this small piece of text:

1. `<a href="oldlink">link</a>`
2. `<a href="newlink">link</a>`

I need to create a Function that takes two varchar and returns something like:

```
--<a href="oldlink">link</a>

++<a href="newlink">link</a>
```

I've found this answer [Compare text differences between two almost identical rows / tables in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22224823/196210). Are there MySQL native function which could help me with this task?

Comment: What is the question you have? What are the problems you get? What are your attempts in creating such a function/stored procedure? How did they fail? If possible provide a [mcve] with the original data and the result/output you want.

Comment: @Progman: thanks for the feedback, I've rewrote the question. Do you think it's clear now? What could I change to improve it?

Comment: I'm still missing a good definition of the **diff patch format**. What, given your example, tells the routine that it should start at `<a href` and end at `</a>`. Is it the HTML tag? Or is that whole piece on one line? We _cannot_ create a routine until this format is exactly specified. Moreover, do you need to do this in MySQL? This seems more like a job for a more general purpose programming language. (finally, what have you tried yourself?)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware: thanks. I think you are right.. it doesn't fit MySQL. However the diff patch format (and the procedure to create a diff) are very well known https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff I thought any developer which use versioning knew it..

Comment: Does this need to be done as a MySQL procedure? Could you retrieve the two runs and run them through `diff`?

Comment: @Schwern: yes, I think I will do that with PHP. Probably MySQL is not the best for this task..